# Formal name of the product of product type

Tags: terminology, type-theory, category-theory, types

What is the formal name in type theory of the operation that creates a "matrix of types" from product types (such as std::tuple in C++)?

For example if we consider `std::tuple<int, float, char> t1`  and `std::tuple<std::string, double> t2` (in C++, but the same question remains for any product type in any language), what would the name of the operation that would construct the following matrix of product types:

- `int, std::string`
- `int, double`
- `float, std::string`
- `float, double`
- `char, std::string`
- `char, double`

Comment: What do you mean by "matrix of types"? Perhaps provide an example.

Comment: That is a type containing the tuples I listed (6 product types with 2 values each)

Comment: That's just a tuple of tuples.

Comment: I am more speaking of the operation, not the type

Comment: Do you mean? `std::tuple<std::tuple<int, std::string>, std::tuple<int, double>, std::tuple<float, std::string>, std::tuple<float, double>, std::tuple<char, std::string>, std::tuple<char, double>>`?

Comment: Yes. But again, what is the name of the operation taking two tuples and producing this tuple of tuples?

Comment: Tupling, pairing, constructing a pair/tuple. I don't think there is a specific name for it.